# PE file format pointers using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, c, file, assembly, portable-executable

I wanted to know the math behind these lines of code. Dealing with pointers. Can someone walk me through the math with the + operators and & bitwise operator in the if statement? I just don't understand it that well.

```
 // check signatures -- must be a PE
    pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMap;
    if(pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) goto cleanup;

    pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)hMap + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if(pNtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) goto cleanup;

// Not dll
 if (pNtHeaders->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL
  && pNtHeaders->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE) goto cleanup;

    // get last section's header...
    pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)hMap + pDosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
    pSection = pSectionHeader;
 pSection += (pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The + operator is just an arithmetic plus.  When used with pointers it now becomes clearer why pointers in C and C++ are typed - it does not just add bytes to the address, but adds the size of whatever the type it is pointing at.

So, for example, if we had:

```
struct stuff x;
struct stuff *p = &x;    /* p now points at x */
p = p + 1;
/* the address at p has been incremented by the sizeof(struct stuff), 
    and is pointing at the next struct stuff in memeory */
```

The & used as a binary operator is bitwise AND, which carries bits that are set in both operands.  For example:

```
unsigned int b = 99;      /* 99 is binary 01100011 */
unsigned int w = b & 6;   /*  6 is binary 00000110 */
/* w is now 2                 2 is binary 00000010 */
```

It looks like in your example code it is used to test if the bitmasks IMAGE_FILE_DLL and IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE are set in the structure members.

Comment: Ya, I noticed these values in the specification: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 ( IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE )

0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 ( IMAGE_FILE_DLL )
----------------------------------------

Comment: +1 and sidebar, the opposite is also true (and rarely talked about) when performing pointer-differencing. If two pointers of the same type are differenced (subtracted), i.e. `size_t n = (p-q);` where p an q are two identically typed pointers, the result is the number of *typed objects* between them; NOT the number of *bytes* (unless the type *is* a char or unsigned char, duh). This can come in *very* handy sometimes.